# Changing the object on which an iterator was created

Tags: java, iterator

Consider the function below:

```
private static void printTrie(Node root){
        Iterator it = root.children.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println((Character)pair.getKey());
            root = (Node)pair.getValue();
            printTrie(root);
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }
    }
```

Here's the definition of `Node`:

```
static class Node {
        private HashMap<Character, Node> children;
        private boolean isCompleteContact;

        public Node(){
            children = new HashMap<Character, Node>();
            isCompleteContact = false;
        }
    }
```

My question is this: in the function I create an `Iterator` called `it` based on `root`. However, halfway through iterating over all the elements exposed by `it`, I reassign `root` to another node. Does this change the behaviour of the `it`? I.e., does `it` still refer to the original `root` or the new value we assign to `root` halfway through the while loop?

Comment: Can't you try it and figure out?

Comment: From the java docs: Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.

Comment: Java is always *pass by value*

Comment: @efekctive that wasn't his question.

Comment: The point being is that he is getting a concurrent mod. exception. It may be worth trying to find the right iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java is always *pass-by-value*,  the reassignment of the `root` reference will not reassign the root object/instance but just the `root` reference.

The statement `root = (Node)pair.getValue();` only reassings the local reference `root` to a new object. You will continue to iterate over the original root object since the iterator was created on the original root object which can't be reassigned due to *pass-by-value* semantics.

Also note that if you add a new value to the `children` `HashMap` while iterating over it, it will result in a `ConcurrentModficationException`. The only thing you can do safetly using the same iterator is remove the current element being iterated by calling `remove` on the `Iterator`

Comment: But if I changed the original root object somehow, the `it` would reflect that change?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by changing the original root object. If you mean changing the *state* of the root object, then yes, it is possible for this change to be reflected in the `iterator` provided that the `iterator` relies on this state and allows such an update. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re) as an example. I don't see how you would reassign the original root object/instance itself (like I said, Java uses pass-by-value semantics always)

Comment: So if I added something to the HashMap halfway through iterating over it, the iterator would be aware of the change in the sense that it would provide access to the new object? Or would I have to create a new iterator to get access to the new object?

Answer (score 2):

It refers to the original object root was referring to. This is because the iterator is derived from the value of the variable root, rather than it, itself, as a reference to that value.

Comment: *rather than it, itself, as a reference to that value*?